# Delphi: extract path file from uninstallstring registry key

Tags: delphi

How detect, in Delphi Seattle, file is exists, if in SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall on UninstallString is parameters e.g:

```
1) "C:\Users\Radek\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe" /background
2) C:\Users\Radek\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe /background
3) C:\PROGRA~2\Raize\CS5\UNWISE.EXE C:\PROGRA~2\Raize\CS5\CS5_EX~1.LOG
4) C:\Program Files (x86)\CollabNet\uninst.exe
```

i need extract only path:

```
1) C:\Users\Radek\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe
2) C:\Users\Radek\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe
3) C:\PROGRA~2\Raize\CS5\UNWISE.EXE
4) C:\Program Files (x86)\CollabNet\uninst.exe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, use [`AnsiExtractQuotedStr()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.AnsiExtractQuotedStr) or [`AnsiDequotedStr()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SysUtils.AnsiDequotedStr).

In the 2nd and 3rd cases, use `Pos()` to find the first space and then use  `Copy()` or `SetLength()` to trim the string to the specified length.

In the 4th case, use it as-is.

Comment: space is problem for 4) but find .exe string is ok

`function VyextrahujExe(UnComm:string):string;
var i:integer;
begin
ShowMessage(UnComm);
// extract text onlny in delmeters
UnComm:=AnsiDeQuotedStr(UnComm, '"');
// find .exe position
i:=pos('.EXE',UpperCase(UnComm));
// delete all behind .exe
Delete(UnComm, i+4, Length(UnComm)-i-3);

result:=UnComm;
end;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**CommandLineToArgvW**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391(v=vs.85).aspx) API function. According to the linked documentation about the [argument conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/88w63h9k(v=vs.85).aspx), the first parsed argument should be the file name:

> **By convention, `argv[0]` is the command with which the program is
>   invoked**, `argv[1]` is the first command-line argument, and so on, until
>   `argv[argc]`, which is always NULL.

So try something like this (not tested, based on [this example](http://www.michael-puff.de/Programmierung/Delphi/Code-Snippets/CommandLineToArgvW.shtml)):

```
uses
  ShellAPI;

function TryGetCommandLineFileName(const CommandLine: string; out FileName: string): Boolean;
type
  TPWideCharArray = array[0..0] of PWideChar;
var
  Count: Integer;
  Arguments: PPWideChar;
begin
  Arguments := CommandLineToArgvW(PChar(CommandLine), Count);
  Result := Assigned(Arguments) and (Count > 0);
  if Result then
  begin
    FileName := TPWideCharArray(Arguments^)[0]); // argv[0] should be the file name
    LocalFree(THandle(Arguments));
  end;
end;
```

Or the [**PathRemoveArgs**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773742(v=vs.85).aspx) API function, which is just for this purpose. But beware that the latter has this note in the reference:

> This function **should not be used** on generic command path templates
>   (from users or the **registry**), but rather it should be used only on
>   templates that the application knows to be well formed.

So in this case I would prefer the first one, but both should work (I assume, cannot test) so long the strings are not malformed.